# error displaying image in IE10

Tags: java, internet-explorer-10

Server:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url/{size}/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getPortfolioFile(HttpServletResponse response,
    @PathVariable("id") int id,
    @PathVariable("size") int size)
{
    File img = provider.getImage(id, size);

    if (img != null) {
        try {
            FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(img), response.getOutputStream());
            String mimeType = img.toURL().openConnection().getContentType();
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            response.setContentLength((int) img.length());
            response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + img.getName() + "\"");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

html:

```
<img src="/url/2/${id}" onerror="$('#c').empty();" />
```

the problem is that IE10 don't display image. response body contains image, headers is 200 OK. whan can it be?

### check in:

- Chrome v43.0.2357.132
- FireFox Developer Edition v40
- IE v10

Comment: Check the response headers on ie10. Also compare headers with a static image

Comment: Try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>` in `head` section.

Comment: @Arpit, this doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the headers before you write the content, else they are ignored.

```
String mimeType = img.toURL().openConnection().getContentType();
response.setContentType(mimeType);
response.setContentLength((int) img.length());
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;         
FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(img), response.getOutputStream());
```

EDIT:
you content-type "binary/octet-stream" does not make sense.
Here I would expect a "image/gif" or other appropriate content type.
I also would eliminate the content-disposition header.

Comment: this is doesn't help too